# Why do i keep getting "connection to the server was unsuccessful. (http://localhost:12896/)"?

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, meteor

I'm using meteor 1.8.1 , when compile for android i use command "meteor run android --mobile-server=http://localhost:3000 --verbose" the app compiles fine but when it launches the app on emulator 
a modal popup comes up and says "connection to the server was unsuccessful. (http://localhost:12896/)"
could there be some config I'm missing?

Comment: Where is your meteor server running on? If you use localhost your server should run on the emulator too.

Comment: yes ,I'm running server on localhost

Comment: Yes? Your server runs on the emulator too? Your server is an Android app? Your answer does not clarify anything.

Comment: @blackapps to be honest I don't understand your point. Yes, the meteor server and the emulator should run on the same machine, and Codee seems to confirm it does. Running meteor on android is not possible, so I suspect you don't really mean what you say ("server should run on the emulator too").

Comment: Codee, I suspect it's about resolving localhost. The emulator resolves localhost to the simulated phone. I think you will need to use a hostname that the emulator can resolve to get to the machine you are running on. Somehow I would assume that you can just drop the `--server` option and meteor would set the right one, but I havn't checked.

Comment: `Yes, the meteor server and the emulator should run on the same machine, and Codee seems to confirm it does.` No he did not. @Christian Fritz. A pitty as when he did i could help him.

Comment: @ blackapps i dont think the server is suppose to run on the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#running-your-app:

> meteor run will try to detect the local IP address of the computer
>   running the command automatically. If this fails, or if you would like
>   your mobile app to connect to a different server, you can specify an
>   address using the --mobile-server option.

So yes, I would try without the `--server` option first. If that fails, you will need to find an IP address or hostname that the emulator can resolve. Presumably your local IP address, check `ifconfig`, would work for this. You can also use

```
ip route get 8.8.8.8 | grep via | sed 's/.*via \(\S*\).*/\1/'
```

to get the IP address of the device you currently use to connect to the internet, which should work.

Comment: thanks il keep trying running the --server  with ip address instead of localhost.